# Android Studio Button Creation

Tags: java, android, menu

I am trying to create a page where I have four buttons, each leading to a separate class in the file. So if button 1 is pressed it takes you to that class. I think I have done the basics but don't know about creating the menu.

```
package com.example.a.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu (menu);
        MenuItem button = menu.add(0, 0, Menu.NONE, "MainActivity");
        MenuItem button1 = menu.add(0, 1, Menu.NONE, "second");
        MenuItem button2 = menu.add(0, 2, Menu.NONE, "third");
        MenuItem button3 = menu.add(0, 3, Menu.NONE, "fourth");


        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case 0:
                    Intent i1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity (i1);
                    return true;
                case 1:
                    Intent i2 = new Intent(this, second.class);
                    startActivity (i2);
                    return true;
                case 2:
                    Intent i3=new Intent(this, third.class);
                    startActivity(i3);
                    return true;
                case 3:
                    Intent i4=new Intent(this, forth.class);
                    startActivity(i4);
                    return true;

                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What did you try searching for before asking this question?

Comment: creating menu android studio

Comment: Try "create menu android" . You are creating a menu in android and the editor you are using is android studio. Hope you have that clear in your mind

Answer (score 0):

Modify /res/menu/main.xml to define menu items

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_up"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
    android:title="Up"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_down"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
    android:title="Down"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_other"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:title="Other"/>
```

In the main activity's onOptionsItemSelected, handle the menu items.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

  switch(item.getItemId()){
  case R.id.action_settings:
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
   startActivity (intent);

   break;
  case R.id.action_up:
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
   startActivity (intent);
   break;
  case R.id.action_down:
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
   startActivity (intent);
   break;
  case R.id.action_other:
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, FourthActivity.class);
   startActivity (intent);
   break;
  default:
         super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   break;
  }

  //Return false to allow normal menu processing to proceed, 
  //true to consume it here.
  return false;
 }

}
```